# Trying to get data from my database using mongoose but instead it returns the query

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to send data from express to react using mongoose when I log `collection.find();` instead of returning every piece of data in my database it returns the query https://pastebin.com/2ShSuPp4

Code: https://pastebin.com/84XAvC0E
when I go to the react app it gives me a 404 error

I didn't write my code in here because for some reason it doesnt recognise javascript when i use the `` brackets

Comment: Check the examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose

Comment: If you look into the Mongoose docs for a find you will need to run an `exec()` https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
app.post("/table", function(req, res) {
  let response = collection.find();
  console.log(response);
  res.send(response);
});
```

The `.find()` method on any model is asynchronous in nature and actually returns a promise to the query. You need to await on the query to get the actual data from the database. And hence, the `response` variable contains the promise.

You need to use either `async/await` syntax or `.then().catch()` syntax to get hold of the data received from the database server.

```js
app.post("/table", async function(req, res) {
  try{
    let response = await collection.find();
    console.log(response);
    res.send(response);
  }catch(e){
    // your error handling logic
  }
});
```

OR using `.then().catch()`

```js
app.post("/table", function(req, res) {
  collection.find()
    .then((response)={
      console.log(response);
      res.send(response);
    })
    .catch((e)=>{
      // your error handling logic
    })    
});
```

Comment: I had to mix your answers to get my app working I used an asynchronous function as well as calling exec() at the end of collection.find() -> collection.find().exec() and lastly i had to use app.get instead of post to send the data for some reason. Anyway i appreciate everyones help greatly